# round results in aggregate table results (pyspark)

Tags: pyspark, aggregate, iris-dataset

Hello how would I round this content of table outputted by this code.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
exprs = {x: "sum" for x in data2.columns[:4]}
data2.groupBy("Species").agg(exprs).show()
```

[image: res]
I've tried

```
round(data2.groupBy("Species").agg(exprs),2).show() #not ok

data2.groupBy("Species").agg(exprs).show().round(2) # not ok
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

round only works on one column. So you have to call it for each column, e.g.

```
agg_cols = data2.columns[:4]
exprs = [sum(col(x)).alias(x) for x in agg_cols]
aggregated_df = data2.groupBy("Species").agg(*exprs)
aggregated_df.select(col("Species"), *[round(c, 2) for c in agg_cols]).show()
```

Comment: I've got this error `TypeError: Column is not iterable`

Comment: In which line? Can you check that agg_cols is a list of strings?

Comment: Yes agg_cols is list of string. It come from this line.
`aggregated_df = data2.groupBy("Species").agg(exprs)
`

Comment: I've edited the answer. Could you try again please?